# Mapbox - Icon rotations in FeatureCollection

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm displaying various ships on a map and I have made real sized polygons to represent them. These are not visible at lower zooms, so I wanted to also add icons representing each ship. The icon is a small arrow that indicates each ship's heading.

```
var ships = {...};

var shipIcons = {
    "id": "shipIcons",
    "type": "symbol",
    "source": {
        "type": "geojson",
        "data": {
            "type": "FeatureCollection",
            "features": []
        }
    },
    "layout": {
        "icon-image": "arrow",
        "icon-rotate": 0,
        "icon-rotation-alignment": "map",
        "icon-allow-overlap": true
    }
};

for(var key in ships){
    shipIcons.source.data.features.push(
        {
            "type": "Point",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [ships[key].long, ships[key].lat]
            }
        }
    );
}

map.addLayer(shipIcons);
```

Is it possible for me to create a unique rotation for each icon? I'd rather not create a layer for each as there may be many ships.

Answer (score 1):

It took awhile, but I finally figured it out.

You can set a "properties" object in each feature and call it from the layout. In this case, the JSON in the loop would be...

```
{
    "type": "Point",
    "properties": {
        "rotate": Number(ships[key].Heading)
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [ships[key].long, ships[key].lat]
    }
}
```

and the "icon-rotate" field would be...

```
"icon-rotate": ["get", "rotate"],
```

This could obviously have more use cases beyond just "icon-rotate".